# Can I get Last write time of a file in SharePoint via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, file, properties

Is it possible to get when was the last WRITE time of a file in a document library by using Powershell?

```
$url = "http://myserver/sites/mysite/shared%20documents/myfile.xlsx"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$lastWriteTimestamp = #...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
$url = "http://myserver/sites/mysite/shared%20documents/myfile.xlsx"
$web = Get-SPWeb http://myserver/sites/mysite
$file = $web.GetFile($url)
$lastWriteTimestamp = $file.Item["Modified"]
```

OR

```
$lastWriteTimestamp =  $file.TimeLastModified
```

Find all properties of `SPFile` in *[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile_properties.aspx)*